# Добавить в select значение, если в столбце есть значение

Tags: sql

Есть таблица tab:

| id | date | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2022-01-18 20:19:08.000 | 2 |
| 001 | 2022-10-18 20:19:08.000 | 1 |
| 001 | 2022-05-18 20:19:08.000 | 2 |
| 001 | 2022-07-18 20:19:08.000 | 2 |
| 001 | 2022-12-18 20:19:08.000 | 4 |
| 001 | 2022-02-18 20:19:08.000 | 2 |

Мне необходимо ранжировать данные по дате и это я сделал:

```
select
t.id,
t.date as startDate,
t.state
from tab t
Order by startDate
```

Проблема в том, что мне надо добавить в select еще одно значение, которого нет в таблице. При этом, если в tab.state есть хотя бы одна строка со значением 4, в select добавляется 'success' AS result а если нет ни в одной строке 4 - что-то вроде 'fail' AS result

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
select
  t.id,
  t.date as startDate,
  t.state,  
  case when exists (select 1 from tab where state = 4) then 'success' else 'fail' end as result
from tab t
order by startDate
```

Уточните диалект SQL.
Например, в T-SQL можно `case` заменить на `iif`, будет короче:

```
iif (exists(select 1 from tab where state = 4), 'success', 'fail') as result
```

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из ТЗ, рекомендую завести переменную статуса и определить её перед выполнение основного запроса, а не вычислять значение для каждой строки таблицы:

```
DECLARE @status VARCHAR(10) = 'fail'

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab WHERE state = 4) SET @status = 'success'

SELECT  t.id,
        t.date as startDate,
        t.state,  
        @status as result
FROM tab t
ORDER BY startDate
```